# Problem importing external jquery files from CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

I have an issue trying to use external jquery files from CDN, to my understanding Jquery files ought to be included in the top most part from other custom jquery files.

I have done the same but I am getting an error which I cannot seem to get away with it no matter how I changed the arrangement of the files from the angular.json file.

Below are the pictures of my setup and error message.

**Angular error, as a result of importing external custom jquery files from CDN**
[[image: [1]]]

**This is my angular.json setup arranged to ensure that jquery is in the top most part**

```
   "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",              
              "src/assets/css/customcss.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [ 
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",  
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "src/assets/js/custom.js"

               ]
```

**This is my angular index.html page where I using the extenal custom jquery library**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> My site </title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   <!-- custom css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
    </head>

<body>

<!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

 <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't include jQuery and jQuery.min in same project. It will fail

Comment: I have removed the jQuery, but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setting in angular.json

```
"scripts": [
            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            "node_modules/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
```

**Don't add script tag to index.html file**

In component TS file you can declare and use it

```
declare const $: any;

ngOnInit() {
   $('#example').DataTable();
}
```

Comment: Remember I am not writing anything on the ts file since I am invoking an already script into my .html file.

Comment: we do not add script to index.html file, you need remove it

Comment: Alternative I tried to download the custom and css files from the source CDN and place it on my assets folder so that I can reference it on the angular.json file.but still experience problems.

Comment: @HienNguyen, your solution is right, but I believe rather then to write it inside ngOnInit(), he/she have write it inside ngAfterViewInit(). Hope this will not cause any error in console. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I only made an sample